# Unity camera always at origin at startup regardless of position in scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, camera, google-project-tango

So I wanted to edit the starting height of the camera in my scene and tried to move the camera up a bit.  Nothing happened.  Also tested it buy moving the camera up a large amount, am I right in assuming that the camera always 'spawns'/'initiates' at (0,0,0), never using the position of it in the scene.

If this assumption is correct how can I possibly get the camera to initiate at the camera position in screen.  I don't really want to move the entire scene to re-position the camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two solutions for this (specifically for TangoUnitySDK):

1. You could modify the PoseController.cs. For example, [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/blob/master/UnityExamples/Assets/TangoPrefabs/Scripts/TangoPoseController.cs#L222) in the example code, you could add an offset vector.
2. Use the [DeltaPoseController](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/blob/master/UnityExamples/Assets/TangoPrefabs/Tango%20Delta%20Camera.prefab) prefab instead of the PoseController. DeltaPoseController will keep the initial position as the starting point, so you could just put it at the place that where you want the application to start.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a simple script where you set the position of your camera in the start() method:

```
void Start()
{
     transform.position += new Vector(0, 100f, 0);
}
```

then just attach the script to your camera

Comment: Wont this modification just be overridden by tango, isn't this exactly the same as moving the camera in the scene editor.  I will try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

just figured it out myself. Hope this helps you!

```
newPose = new Vector3(0,10,0);

yourTangoCamera.GetComponent<TangoDeltaPoseController> ().SetPose (newPose,yourTangoCamera.transform.rotation);
```

Read more about SetPose here:
 https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/reference/class/tango-delta-pose-controller#class_tango_delta_pose_controller_1a19c0ea02c4c538ffcf7cdc3423b222b8